# Non-equivariant map between group modules

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group, and let $M$ and $N$ be "$G$-modules", i.e. abelian groups equipped with an action of $G$.
Let $f:M\to N$ be an additive map which is not *quite* $G$-equivariant, but rather, satisfies the following identity for all $m\in M$:
$$
f(g\cdot m) = \phi(g) \cdot g \cdot f(m) ,
$$
where $\phi:G\to G$ is a fixed group homomorphism, independent of $m$.

First of all: does this property have a name, something like "pseudo-equivariant"?

Second: let $M/G$ and $N/G$ be the quotients under the action of $G$. Define the following map $f':M/G\to M/G$:
$$
f(Gm) := Gf(m).
$$
This map is additive, and well-defined, even if $f$ is not equivariant. More in general, what is the most general property that a map $f$ needs to satisfy in order to descend to the quotients?

(This question is similar in spirit to [this other one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048446/non-equivariant-map-that-may-descend-to-the-quotient).)

Comment: This map is not well defined, unless $f$ maps orbit into an orbit.

Comment: @freakish isn't $f(g\cdot m) = \phi(g)\cdot g\cdot f(m)$ enough to assure that it maps an orbit into an orbit?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I've misread the definition.

Comment: Anyway, the most general property for $f$ to induce a map on quotients is that $f$ has to map orbits into orbits. I don't think that your "pseudo-equivariant" property has any name, but note that if $G$ is abelian then $(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot \varphi(g)\cdot x$ is a group action and so this is simply again an equivariant map with a group action on the right side slightly modified.